# Derived class selection at run time

Tags: java

I have a situation where my code structure looks like.

```
class BaseClass .. 
class DerivedClass1 extends BaseClass ...
class DerivedClass2 extends BaseClass ...
class DerivedClass3 extends BaseClass ...
```

Now at the run time I want to use any one of the derived class based on an integer number `classId`.

Something like,

```
BaseClass myObj = new ((classId == 1) ? DerivedClass1 : (classId == 2) ? DerivedClass2 : DerivedClass3
```

I want some sort of random behavior. For example at one time my application might draw a line while at some other time it might draw a circle.
How to code above functionality in Java?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751176/changing-object-initializer-constructor-depending-on-method-input/22751293#22751293

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use polymorphism and whatever style (switch/if-else) you want. For instance:

BaseClass myObj;

```
switch(classId): {
  case 1:
     myObj = new DerivedClass1();
     break;
  case 2:
     myObj = new DerivedClass2();
     break;
  case 3:
     myObj = new DerivedClass3();
     break
  default:
     throw RuntimeException ("Id not recognized);
}
Do something with object;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an anti-pattern as it is similar to having tagged classes, which is advisable against according to [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683).

In general, the way to do this sort of thing in java is to have a factory that instantiates objects of a sub-type of `BaseClass`. This might or might not be helpful in your case because you might need to dynamically generate different instances based on the context.

I wouldn't recommend using integer ids in general as it turns out not to be very robust (what if the integer does not map to a type?). You could use the `Class<? extends BaseClass>` object instead and instantiate via reflection or nested if statements.

What's your specific use case? More information might help us come up with a cleaner and more robust solution.

Comment: Thanks @Giovanni. I want some sort of random behavior. For example at one time my application might draw a line while at some other time it might draw a circle.

Comment: Then the integer approach seems appropriate. Draw a number from 0 to N and then create your instance of `BaseClass` from a `switch` statement as per other answer.